# How to use light probes in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

In Blender Internal we can use light probes (setting: angmap) to illuminate scenes. I'd like to use the same light probes in Cycles as in Blender Internal. However, I can't find the right settings in Cycles and therefore the background is distorted.

Any ideas how to fix it?